# simple program Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, eclipse

Can anyone help, I am using eclipse and I am getting this error on every new class I write. What is the problem.

```
package joe;
public class Joe {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary.main(BreakDictionary.java:40)
```

Comment: The code provided has nothing to do with that error. Post the `com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary` code.

Comment: Are you asking why you have this error or why the main of BreakDictionary is launched every time you're trying to launch this class?

Comment: Obicere is right, the problem is you're not launching the program you think you are!

Comment: Weirdest duplicate question I've seen.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the right class? If you're in eclipse, right click and click run as java application.  Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the run button in the toolbar above the text editor. If you click the little arrow next to and open the dropdown, you'll see that you aren't running what you think you are running. If you want to add a new run configuration for a new class, you can do that by clicking the `Run configurations...` link in that dropdown.

I think the default behavior with Eclipse is to run whatever class you're currently looking at in the text editor. If that doesn't happen, consider restarting Eclipse. That has happened to me in the past.